# How to solve $|2x +1|< 1/4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How do you solve $$|2x +1|< \frac{1}4$$

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $|x| < a$ means $-a < x < a$. So your inequality is the same as saying

$$-\frac{1}{4} < 2x + 1 < \frac{1}{4}$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: What does $|x| > a$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

note that here $|x|$ means $-a<x<a $.

You want the interval that is surrounding  $x$. You're looking for an interval that has $x$ in it, with numbers that are less than $x$ and numbers that are more than $x$.

So you have:

$$|2x+1|<1/4\Rightarrow -1/4<2x+1<1/4$$

subtract the $1$ from $2x+1$:

$(-1-1/4)<2x<(1/4-1)$

then divide by $2$:

$((-1-1/4)\div2)<x<((1/4-1)\div2)$

Comment: That's a disturbing use of "="

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 is it wrong?

Comment: I'll fix it. ${}{}$

Comment: But now I see another problem: $|x| = x$ is not a true statement!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 yes you're right, i thought that in this context it was.